# Is 23:59:59.999 end of day?

Tags: datetime, time

In my project involving dates calculation I am wondering what is really end of day coming from a previous question:

[extract date ranges grouped by day from time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994654/extract-date-ranges-grouped-by-day-from-time-intervals)

Is 23:59:59:999 end of day or is it 24:00:00:000?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure whether there is one specific answer. Can you add some context?

Comment: Depends on if there is a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) or not.

Comment: Even without leap seconds, what is the resolution? Maybe there's a time like `23:59:59.999999`? It's better to compare just the date part of the timestamp or compare your timestamp to see if it is strictly less than the `00:00:00` on the next day.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net the property Hour is between 0 to 23 so I think 23:59:59:999 is the correct answer